# Change classes and display message when form is submitted with Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using ngMessages to display error messages with my form validation and this is working.

Now my problem is when I submit the form I want to change the classes from being valid (green border) to their normal state, which is just css on the inputs. Also if all the fields are valid a text message should display above the form that the form has been sent but it doesn't seem to be working with the $valid.

After a few seconds the message disappears.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZidK8ja9Z7YkkKUaay6B?p=preview)

my code

css

```
input {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 10px;

}
.invalid-field {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.valid-field {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
.sent {
    color: green;   
}
```

html/angular

```
<form novalidate name="contactForm">
    <div ng-messages="contactForm.$valid" ng-if="contactForm.$submitted">
        <div ng-message="valid">
            <span class="sent">Your message has been sent!</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.nameField.$touched || contactForm.$submitted, 'valid-field': contactForm.nameField.$valid}" 
        type="text" name="nameField" placeholder="Full name*"
        ng-model="contactName"
        minlength="2"
        required >
    <div ng-messages="contactForm.nameField.$error" ng-if="contactForm.$submitted || contactForm.nameField.$touched">
        <div ng-message="required">
            <span class="error">Name is required</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">
            <span class="error">Name must be 2 characters long</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.emailField.$touched || contactForm.$submitted, 'valid-field': contactForm.emailField.$valid}"
        type="email" name="emailField" placeholder="Email*"
        ng-model="contactEmail"
        required>
    <div ng-messages="contactForm.emailField.$error" ng-if="contactForm.$submitted || contactForm.emailField.$touched">
        <div ng-message="required"><span class="error">Email is required</span></div>
        <div ng-message="email"><span class="error">Email is not valid</span></div>
    </div>

    <button class="send-btn" type="submit">Send form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: make  a plunker. it would be very helpful for you and for us too.

Comment: I will edit my question with a plunker in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I'm afraid that you can't do what you need directly, because if you change the conditional there are 2 states which will conflict with each other:

*The user fills the form correctly and submits* VS *The user press Submit, then fills a field correctly*

In the **second case** the field won't be show the `valid-field` green border.

---

What you should do is make a function which checks the valid fields, and execute it on the submit, then set a flag on `true` for a class global on your form which will override your current `valid`/invalid states

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HFFght?p=preview) is the working solution

```
//Validate States
$scope.validateSuccessSubmit = function(){
      if($scope.contactForm.nameField.$valid && 
        $scope.contactForm.emailField.$valid &&
          $scope.contactForm.$submitted) {
            $scope.formCompleted = true;
          }

    };
```

---

```
<!-- Form -->
    <form novalidate name="contactForm" ng-class="{'form-completed' : formCompleted}">
```

---

```
/*CSS*/
.form-completed input{
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

*Previous incorrect answer:*

<s>Just add the `!$submitted` condition on the `valid-field` class</s>

```
ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.nameField.$touched || contactForm.$submitted, 
'valid-field': contactForm.nameField.$valid && !contactForm.$submitted}" 

//And 

ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.emailField.$touched || contactForm.$submitted,
 'valid-field': contactForm.emailField.$valid  && !contactForm.$submitted}"
```

Comment: when i added this to my plunker the borders went from green to red

Comment: Sorry i'l fix the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code it will work fine but what you need to is write css class like:

```
    .initial
   {
     1px solid darkgray;  
   }
```

and  use the following html for ng-class of you input elements.

```
 ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.nameField.$touched && !contactForm.nameField.$valid, 
 'valid-field': contactForm.nameField.$valid&& !contactForm.$submitted , 
   'initial':contactForm.nameField.$valid && contactForm.$submitted}" 

  ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.emailField.$touched && !contactForm.emailField.$valid,
  'valid-field': contactForm.emailField.$valid && !contactForm.$submitted , 
   'initial':contactForm.emailField.$valid && contactForm.$submitted}"
```

And finally I for the "Your message has been sent!" message you need to write

```
     <div ng-messages="contactForm.$valid" ng-if="contactForm.$submitted && contactForm.$valid">

       <span class="sent">Your message has been sent!</span>

   </div>
```

Comment: I was verified and it is working fine. but one thing you should know that is there any    <div ng-message="valid">.

Comment: This solution has a defect, If the user press submit, without entering anything, then fill the fields correctly, the green border won't be shown