# Validate and style angular form inputs on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom angular directive to validate an input. I have added the validation to occur onblur. Depending the result of this validation the input will acquire a css class (green for positive, red for negative). This currently works a treat.
However, the issue I am having is if a user clicks the submit button without using any of the inputs. As the validation happens on blur the validators do not run and so the input classes do not get set.

I have tried the solution mentioned in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969094/change-classes-and-display-message-when-form-is-submitted-with-angular). Although this works fine it doesn't seem quite right having all that logic against an input style within the view, it feels very bloated. I was hoping there was a way to make it more generic using a directive EG

```
    ng-class="{'invalid-field': contactForm.nameField.$touched ||
 contactForm.$submitted, 'valid-field': contactForm.nameField.$valid}" 
          type="text" name="nameField" placeholder="Full name*"
          ng-model="contactName"
          minlength="2"
          required >
```

Should things like this be managed in the directive? Or is it correct to have the markup mentioned above against each input in a form?

Thanks